# how to send list of id`s select from checkbox in a jqgrid in partialview to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i need to send a list of values selected from checkboxes in each of the columns in the jqgrid, my problem is to send this info to the controller, 
this is some of the code that i need to send from this partialview to the controller

this is my jqgrid:

```
 jQuery("#TratamientoGrid").jqGrid({
      url:"Tratamiento/SearchGridTreat",
      datatype:"json",     
      colNames: ['ID', 'Nombre', 'Apellido', 'Nº Doc', 'Estado', 'Fecha Inicio'],
      jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
      colModel: [
                { name: 'TratamientoId',index: 'Id', key: true, width: 40 },
                { name: 'Paciente.Nombre',index: 'pacienteNombre', width: 125 }, 
                { name: 'Paciente.Apellido', index: 'pacienteApellido', width: 125 },
                { name: 'Paciente.NumeroDocumento', index:'numeroDocumento', width: 75 }, 
                { name: 'TratamientoEstado.Nombre', index: 'estado', width: 125 }, 
                { name: 'FechaInicioTratamiento', formatter: 'date', index: 'fechaInicio', width: 100 }, 
            ],
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
            loadonce: true,
            pager: '#TratamientoPag',
            sortname: 'ID',
            caption: 'Imprimir código QR de Tratamiento',
            multiselect: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth: true,
            onSelectRow: function(id) {               
                var index = listOfIds.indexOf(id);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                     listOfIds.push(id);                    
                }                                       
                else
                {
                    listOfIds.splice(index, 1);
                }                
                document.getElementById('lblCantSelected').innerHTML = listOfIds;//to show ids
            }
       });
       jQuery("#TratamientoGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#TratamientoPag', {  edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false  });
```

this is a button where i need to send the ids to the controller

```
function getTreatmentsSelected(id) {
        var tlist;    
        tlist = jQuery("#TreatmentGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow') ; 
        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("TreatmentDoSomething", "Treatment")',
            type:'post',
            data:{List: tlist},
            success:function(data){
                alert("Done");
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is where i need to get the list of id`s

```
  public ActionResult TreatmentDoSomething()!
        {
             return PartialView("_TreatmentDoSomething");
        }
```

Comment: How is the structure of that list? You'll need a viewModel with the same structure to serialize it.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code ?